# How to load pydev data to postgresql

Tags: python, eclipse, postgresql, pydev

My code functions. When running, it displays "Error %s % e" but when I go to postgresql the data doesn't upload there in anyway whatsoever. What should I do?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import psycopg2
import sys


con = None

try:
con = psycopg2.connect("host='localhost' dbname='test123' user='postgres' password='XXX'")   
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Products(Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Name VARCHAR(20), Price INT)")
cur.execute("INSERT INTO Products VALUES(1,'Milk',5)")
cur.execute("INSERT INTO Products VALUES(2,'Sugar',7)")
cur.execute("INSERT INTO Products VALUES(3,'Coffee',3)")
cur.execute("INSERT INTO Products VALUES(4,'Bread',5)")
cur.execute("INSERT INTO Products VALUES(5,'Oranges',3)")
con.commit()
except psycopg2.DatabaseError as e:
    if con:
    con.rollback()

print ("Error %s % e")
sys.exit(1)

finally:   
if con:
    con.close()
```

Comment: Is the formatting of this code the same as it is in your script? (If so, it's completely messed up) If you're receiving the error message, what makes you think this code functions?

Answer (score 0):

To start, your code should be formatted like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
-- coding: utf-8 --
import psycopg2
import sys

con = None

try:
    con = psycopg2.connect("host='localhost' dbname='test123' user='postgres' password='XXX'")   
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Products(Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Name 
 VARCHAR(20), Price INT)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Products VALUES(1,'Milk',5)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Products VALUES(2,'Sugar',7)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Products VALUES(3,'Coffee',3)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Products VALUES(4,'Bread',5)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Products VALUES(5,'Oranges',3)")
    con.commit()
except psycopg2.DatabaseError as e:
    if con:
        con.rollback()
    print ("Error %s % e")
    sys.exit(1)
finally:   
    if con:
        con.close()
```

if you're receiving the message "Error ..." then your code is not working as you expect it to. You should break it up into different sections or else manually run these commands in the Python terminal to debug where the issue is. - This is not really an answer, but hopefully we can work this one out since your question has not got enough information for an answer.. try running the following and see which error you hit:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
-- coding: utf-8 --
import psycopg2
import sys

try:
    con = psycopg2.connect("host='localhost' dbname='test123' user='postgres' password='XXX'")   
    cur = con.cursor()
except Exception:
    print("Failed to open a connection")
    sys.exit(1)

try:
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Products(Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Name 
 VARCHAR(20), Price INT)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Products VALUES(1,'Milk',5)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Products VALUES(2,'Sugar',7)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Products VALUES(3,'Coffee',3)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Products VALUES(4,'Bread',5)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Products VALUES(5,'Oranges',3)")
    con.commit()
except Exception as e:
    print("Failed to insert data into the database")
    sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The formatting/indentations are correct on eclipse, I just didn't do all of them here (as long as it looks as a code, right?) But I am just wondering why the data does not get uploaded to postgresql.

somehow trying to follow these steps: https://pythonspot.com/en/python-database-postgresql/